# Store current page data in a variable, in the same format/structure as an Ajax html response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm storing/saving my History Ajax call responses in an array (jQuery). So on ajax load success I store the response data in an array so I can use it and apply/clone later on (for js side cache).

```
page_cache = [];

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (data) {
    var $response = $(data);
    page_cache[url] = $response;
  }
});
```

So far so good, BUT now I need `the equivalent of the ajax call response data`, but on **the current page** so that I can stor/save it already on **page load**.

But struggled finding a way..

Been trying:

```
page_cache[url] = $('html').data();
```

... but no luck..

Any suggestions?

Comment: after caching what are you doing with the $response? do you set it to some other div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire page in the variable, you can use it:

```
var $html = $('html').clone();
$html.find('body').html($response);

page_cache[url] = $html;
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but $('html').html(); doesn't seem to give me the same result as the response data of an ajax html call.

Comment: You want to store in page_cache[url] the value of the html with the $response, but without updating the page?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want to store the current page html data on page load (in an equivalent format of an Ajax html call so I can use them in the same way).

Comment: The response is stored in <body>? I'll update my answer. Check it now

Comment: Thanks! Works.. (or at least without the $response in html())

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var page_cache =[];
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (data) {

    page_cache[url] = data;
    $('html').html(data);
  }
});
```

for searching:

```
$('html').html(page_cache[url]);
```

for current page html:

```
url = window.location;
page_cache[url] = $('html').html()
```

Comment: $('html').html(); doesn't seem to give me the same result as the response data of an ajax html call..

Comment: No errors storing it, but when I clone and apply it the same way as I do with the ajax response I do get an error. Undefined.. So $('html').html(); doesn't seem to be equivalent of Ajax html response data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to get the `body` part with `$('body').html();` ?

You can save the html with `page_cache[url] = $('body').html();`
and get it back with `$('body').html(page_cache[url]);`

Comment: If you have scripts, and you have at least jQuery, you'll be unable to clone `<head></head>` part. If it is irrelevant for you, can you try cloning `<body></body>` instead? This way you shouldn't be getting javascript errors if you don't have scripts in `<body></body>` part as well. I'm editing my answer now to reflect these changes.